# Fast.ai username and password

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

When I was trying to http://localhost:8080/tree after creating a GCP instance, it asks for a username and password.

How to proceed?

Comment: Please share a minimum reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is minimal and readable, exactly what I want to ask.

Comment: yes, but not reproducible